# Datatable Plugin for CakePHP 4

Tags: cakephp, datatables, cakephp-4.x

I have been upgrading my application from cakephp 3 to cakephp 4. I was using **fheider/cakephp-datatables** and I have come across **ypnos-web/cakephp-datatables** where both support cakephp 3.

I am currently looking for a cakephp-datatable plugin which supports cakephp 4.

If anybody has an idea, I would be happy.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the built-in [pagination](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/pagination.html) is what you are looking for ? you can do advanced dynamic database links with your HTML tables.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully use ypnos-web/cakephp-datatables on CakePHP 4.2.7.  It works very well for me.

You might have to play around a bit to get it working correctly.  Read some of the [issues](https://github.com/ypnos-web/cakephp-datatables/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aclosed) (open and closed) on the ypnos-web/cakephp-datatables github repository and you can likely get it working.

Good Luck!